# rails time input shows different format on edit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a timepicker that inputs the time like this: 12:30.

After submitting the show of the model also shows the time like this 12:30.

But when i want to edit the file the time shows up like this: 2000-01-01 12:30:00 UTC

How do is set up the correct format fot this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use Ruby in-built time formatting like this:

```
t = Time.now                   #=> 2007-11-19 08:37:48 -0600
t.strftime("%I:%M")            #=> "08:37"
```

More info and explanation can be found [here](http://apidock.com/ruby/Time/strftime)

Comment: But how do you format an input field with simple form: <%= f.input :start_time, as: :string %>

Answer (score 0):

```
<%= f.input :start_time, as: :string, input_html: { value: resource.start_time && resource.start_time.strftime("%H:%M") } %>
```

Fixed it by using this(NOTE: I am using inherited resources and simple form)